# Can't update/upgrade du to "Could not execute 'apt-key' to verify signature"

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, gnupg, 16.04

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 last week on my server on a Digital Ocean droplet and since then I can't update nor upgrade anything on my server.
Ma version `Linux 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:31:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I get this error after a `sudo apt-get update` :

```
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease [23.9 kB]
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                          
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                                                                    
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]                                       
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Could not execute 'apt-key' to verify signature (is gnupg installed?)
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease     
  Could not execute 'apt-key' to verify signature (is gnupg installed?)
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Err:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Could not execute 'apt-key' to verify signature (is gnupg installed?)
Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Err:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Could not execute 'apt-key' to verify signature (is gnupg installed?)
Fetched 272 kB in 0s (363 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial         InRelease: Could not execute 'apt-key' to verify signature (is gnupg installed?)
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease: Could not execute 'apt-key' to verify signature (is gnupg installed?)
W: GPG error: https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial Release: Could not execute 'apt-key' to verify signature (is gnupg installed?)
W: The repository 'https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease: Could not execute 'apt-key' to verify signature (is gnupg installed?)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease: Could not execute 'apt-key' to verify signature (is gnupg installed?)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease: Could not execute 'apt-key' to verify signature (is gnupg installed?)
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not execute 'apt-key' to verify signature (is gnupg installed?)
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Could not execute 'apt-key' to verify signature (is gnupg installed?)
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Could not execute 'apt-key' to verify signature (is gnupg installed?)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Could not execute 'apt-key' to verify signature (is gnupg installed?)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I checked for `apt-key` which is there and working.

Comment: For a part solution I added Digital Ocean repository mirrors with which the system had no problem so I have been able to update my applications and my system.
But the problem is still here and the update fail for all official repos

Comment: I've got these errors too, and haven't found a way to solve it. Replacing repositories with Digital Ocean ones doesn't work, and my investigation shows that there might be some call errors with apt-get, apt-key and /usr/lib/apt/methods/gpgv, but no further information with strace or bash debugging. Well one more clue: this is the only server of mines on DO which is running on i386 (surprisingly).

Comment: Same problem here... Digital Ocean, 16.04 i386 involved too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem on my Ubuntu droplet at Digital Ocean (after a distro upgrade).

Just upgrade your kernel in the digital ocean administration site (yes, it's weird). There is a "kernel" option in the menu on the left side where you can select a new kernel image.

In my case the upgrade was from 3.x to 4.x series

Answer (score 11):

Changing the permission of `/tmp` back to [their defaults](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71625/271588) worked for me:

```
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Comment: thanks ,this works for me

Comment: Because apt-key is often a shell script first, this can happen when the shell in the shebang is missing. If you `head /usr/bin/apt-key` and see `#!/bin/sh` then see if the file is there. `ls /bin/sh`. If it isn't there then consider that your system might be very broken. You could try making a soft link `ln -s /usr/bin/sh /bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I played with AppArmor and enabled complain mode on `sshd`. Disabling it by `aa-disable /usr/sbin/sshd` and re-connecting fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same problem and "fixed it" by downgrading to the version of apt present in 15.10.

In my case, I did the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-updates main'
sudo apt-get update # and ignore the errors
sudo aptitude install apt=1.0.10.2ubuntu2
```

And choose the less disruptive option. **WARNING: Choosing a bad option might remove important packages from your system, proceed with caution.**
I chose the following option:

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

  Remove the following packages:                                                       
1)      libapt-inst2.0                                                                     
2)      libapt-pkg5.0                                                                      

  Install the following packages:                                                      
3)      libapt-inst1.7 [1.0.10.2ubuntu2 (wily-updates)]                                    

  Downgrade the following packages:                                                    
4)      apt-transport-https [1.2.10ubuntu1 (now, xenial) -> 1.0.10.2ubuntu2 (wily-updates)]
5)      apt-utils [1.2.10ubuntu1 (now, xenial) -> 1.0.10.2ubuntu2 (wily-updates)]          
6)      aptitude [0.7.4-2ubuntu2 (now, xenial) -> 0.7.3-1ubuntu1.1 (wily-updates)]         
7)      aptitude-common [0.7.4-2ubuntu2 (now, xenial) -> 0.7.3-1ubuntu1.1 (wily-updates)]  
8)      python-apt [1.1.0~beta1build1 (now, xenial) -> 1.0.1ubuntu0.1 (wily-updates)]      
9)      python3-apt [1.1.0~beta1build1 (now, xenial) -> 1.0.1ubuntu0.1 (wily-updates)]     

  Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                                         
10)     libapt-pkg5.0 recommends apt (>= 1.2.10ubuntu1)                                    


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply unfortunetly I got rid of the server with the problem and bought a new one (the old one was 4 years old :p) so I cannot test this but it seem like a good solution.
I'll let anyone who has this problem try the solution and tell me if it fixes the problem.